# Excel Formula - IF/OR

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I'm trying to run a running total where if the conditions are met with *"Won"* or *"Placed"* it will automatically run the sum.

However part of this formula is not working the way I would like as it's displaying **FALSE** in the column when *"Won"* is the selection.

When *"Placed"* is selected is runs the sum fine.

Original formula:

`=IF(I3="Won",(E3*(G3-1))*0.95,-E3)`

Formula with Placed added:

```
=IF(OR(I3="Won"),OR(I3="Placed"),(F3*(H3-1))*0.95)
```

Sorry if I haven't explained this well as I'm not very good with excel!  Any help would be greatly appreciated!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The contents of the OR must be within the formula, not separated, and you need to specify something for the else case:
`=IF(OR(I3="Won",I3="Placed"),(F3*(H3-1))*0.95, <else>)`

Your version is basically saying `=IF(OR(I3="Won")`, then show `OR(I3="Placed")` ( which is true or false) and else `(F3*(H3-1))*0.95`